# Cakephp bcrypt saving empty field

Tags: cakephp, bcrypt

I'm trying to set up bcrypt for my cakephp app. I've set it up before, on another app, and that worked. But, after basically copy / pasting the encryption code from one app to the other, it's saving the password as blank.

The database is setup correctly with the password field being a varchar(225).

I've come to the conclusion that the following line of code is what's causing the problem;

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $hash = Security::hash($this->data['User']['password'], 'blowfish');
        $this->data['User']['password'] = $hash;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I were to take out this beforeSave function, my password would save correctly, as plaintext. If I were to replace

```
$this->data['User']['password'] = $hash;
```

with

```
$this->data['User']['password'] = 'testpassword';
```

It would correctly save the password as testpassword.

My AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' =>'Blowfish',
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'fronts', 'action'=>'index'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);
```

My Form:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php 
        echo $this->form->input('username', array('placeholder' => 'Username', 'label' => false));
        echo $this->form->input('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'label' => false));
        echo $this->form->submit('CREATE', array('class' => 'button')); 
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

When trying to login, though I know it won't work, I get this error

```
Authentication adapter Blowfish was not found.
```

Comment: Can you post or look into the form you have setup? Maybe a name of a field is wrong

Comment: Good idea, just edited OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beforesave appears to be correct. I am using the same thing essentially. Here is my code.

I also setup blowfish in my beforefilter, had problems with the other way

```
$this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
   'Blowfish' => array( 
      'userModel' => 'Account',
      'fields' => array('username' => 'act_username', 'password' => 'act_password')
   )
);
```

The only other difference is my form button has this for submit

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array('id' => 'submit', 'type' => 'submit'));
```

Note this as of 2.4 the blowfish encryption is changing, bcrypt only in 2.3: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-bcrypt-for-passwords

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't really do much. Still returns blank passwords in the database

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: 2.2.9... I just realized that bcrypt wasn't implemented till 2.3 right? dammmn woops. I just downloaded the version at the top, assuming it was the most recent one. Is it possible to update my version without losing my progress? EDIT: Fixed all of it. Thanks for pointing that out :)